# Existence of Derivative at a Point

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$ and I have to find where it's derivative as well as any points where it doesn't exist. The derivative is pretty easy to find, $f'(x)=\frac{1}{(1+|x|)^{2}}$. This derivative obviously exists at $x\neq0$, but having absolute values and whatnot, I was worried about the existence at $x=0$.
Using the definition of the derivative at 0; $$f'(0)=\lim_{h \to0}(\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h})=\lim_{h \to0}(\frac{1}{|h|+1})=1$$

This limit clearly exists and equals 1, from both the left and the right,  as well as agreeing with the general expression for the derivative from above. So, it seems $f$ should be differentiable everywhere.
However, my book is claiming that at $x=0$, $f$ isn't differentiable. Is there something I'm missing about the definition of differentiability at a point, or have I missed something else entirely? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think that you are correct.

Comment: The fonction is differentiable at $0$ but the derivative is (may be a typo) $\frac 1 {(1+|x|)^2}$, and that one is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @nicomezi You seem to be saying the derivative isn't differentiable at zero, but I think that is irrelevant to whether *the function itself* is or not differentiable at zero.

Comment: @Joanpemo Of course, this was just to prevent a possible mistake.

Comment: @nicomezi Thank you, I see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way: why don't you write down explicitely your function?:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac x{1-x}=-1+\frac1{1-x}\;,&x<0\\{}\\\frac x{1+x}=1-\frac1{1+x}\;,&x\ge 0\end{cases}$$

Thus, the function's clearly differentiable at any $\;x\neq0\;$ . At zero we have:

$$\begin{align*}&\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac1{1-x}=1\\{}\\&\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1{1+x}=1\end{align*}$$

Since both one-sided limits defining $\;f'(0)\;$ exist finitely and are equal we have that $\;f'(0)=1\;$ , so the function indeed is differentiable everywhere.